# Finding shortest unique prefix length using map/reduce

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I have a list of strings (from documents in CouchDB).

I want to find the minimum prefix length so that all shortened strings (taking the first LEN characters) are unique.

For example:

- aabb
- aabc
- abcd

should give: LEN is three.

Is it possible to write this as a map/reduce function ?

Comment: Looking at your example I would have expected "LEN = 4" as you show two lines that start with "aab".

Comment: If the list is not too long, you can get it easily with a [list function](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html).

Answer (score 0):

Doing it the brute force way:

MAP: Create for each input record "ABCDE" records with the keys 
 - "A"
 - "AB"
 - "ABC"
 - "ABCD"
 - "ABCDE"

REDUCE:

- IF you have 1 value in the iterator output: "length(key)"   "true"
- If you have more than one 1 value in the iterator output: "length(key)"   "false"

MAP: Identity mapper

REDUCE: Output "true" if all input values are true. Else output false (or nothing);

That should result in a true for all lengths that are "unique"